# Regex exclude ending characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex findall to parse a html page. Using `: (\d{4,9})$(?<!#\*)`, I am able to exclude items that ends in # or *, but I also want to parse from items that end in other characters. Below is a example of what I am trying to achieve.

input string

```
test: 11111###
test: 222222
test: 3333333<br>
```

expected output

```
["222222", "3333333"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
:\s*(\d+)(?![#*\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/48QjDY/1). *Details*:

- `:` - colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?![#*\d])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `#`, `*` or a digit immediately to the right of the current location.